# Set interval in php

Tags: php

> Do we have any function or piece of code to call a particular function after a specific time interval as setInterval in Javascript.

Comment: Have you searched google? Like `setInterval in PHP`? I got this first page which is quite good in my opinion... http://tiffanybbrown.com/2011/10/25/setinterval-in-php/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP terminates when the request is done, so it isn't possible.

You can use a cron at the linux level.

Answer (score 2):

[`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep) inside a loop is probably the closest thing. PHP isn't designed for that, really.

Comment: Heh, then set the max execution time to 31556940 in your php.ini. That will last you a year.

Comment: @Jonathan Actually, I'm fairly sure `sleep` time doesn't count towards execution time.

Comment: Of course, but you would still need enough to run the actual script.

Comment: `0` would work well for that ;)

Comment: When I was writing that comment, I wondered if 0 was a valid param and assumed against it. That's really surprising.

Comment: I use it frequently for me console programs ^_^